# ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for DataService in D:/appangular/src/app/services/data.service.ts: (?, [object Object])

Tags: angular, typescript

When I run `ng build --prod` I get this error .

**data.service.ts**

```
import { BadInput } from './../common/bad-input';
import { AppError } from './../common/app-error';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NotFoundError } from '../common/not-found-error';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private url : string ,private http : HttpClient) { }

  getAll(){
    return this.http.get(this.url).
    pipe(map(response => response),
    catchError(
      this.handleError
    )         
    )} 

  create(resource){
    return this.http.post(this.url,resource).
    pipe(
      catchError(
        this.handleError
      )
    )}

  update(resource){
    return this.http.put(this.url,resource).
    pipe(
      catchError(
        this.handleError
      )
    )}

  delete(resource){
    return this.http.delete(this.url+'/'+resource.id).
    pipe(
      catchError(
        this.handleError
      )
    )}

    private handleError(error : Response){
      if(error.status===404){
        return throwError(new NotFoundError(error));
      }
      if(error.status===400){
        return throwError(new BadInput(error))
      }
      return throwError(new AppError(error))
    }}
```

Comment: Where *did* you expect the DI system to get the URL from?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need this?

```
import { BadInput } from './../common/bad-input';
import { AppError } from './../common/app-error';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NotFoundError } from '../common/not-found-error';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  getAll(url : string){
    return this.http.get(url).
    pipe(map(response => response),
    catchError(
      this.handleError
    )         
    )} 

  create(url : string, resource){
    return this.http.post(url,resource).
    pipe(
      catchError(
        this.handleError
      )
    )}

  update(url : string, resource){
    return this.http.put(url,resource).
    pipe(
      catchError(
        this.handleError
      )
    )}

  delete(url : string, resource){
    return this.http.delete(url+'/'+resource.id).
    pipe(
      catchError(
        this.handleError
      )
    )}

    private handleError(error : Response){
      if(error.status===404){
        return throwError(new NotFoundError(error));
      }
      if(error.status===400){
        return throwError(new BadInput(error))
      }
      return throwError(new AppError(error))
    }}
```